# if condition in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i want to add a class on a click function in "a" tag and if my div nearest a tag has class "jitender" then wana alert.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".Cmnew").find("a").click(function () {
                $(this).addClass("jitender");
                if($(".Cmnew").closest("a").className() == "jitender") {
                    alert("helllo")
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Cmnew">
        <a href="#">first</a>
        <a href="#">second</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `if` is not looking for a div, it's selecting an anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(".Cmnew").find("a").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("jitender");
        if ($(this).siblings("a:first").hasClass("jitender")) {
            alert("helllo")
        }
    });
})​;​
```

**[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/A3gsF/5/)**

Another solution

```
$(function() {
    $(".Cmnew").find("a").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("jitender");
        if ($(this).siblings("a.jitender:first").length) {
            alert("helllo")
        }
    });
});​
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/A3gsF/6/)**

#### When do you get alert

- First click on any link, this will add class to clicked link
- Then click on another link and you will get the alert, because its neighbor has class you have searched

Comment: sir i want to alert only when my first child a tag have jitender class

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
if($(".Cmnew").closest("a").hasClass("jitender")){
...alert
```

Or

```
if($(".Cmnew").children("a").hasClass("jitender")){
 ... alert
```

Comment: yes your second function is working but i want to add this function only closest a tag to my div